# Adding Comment in my report menu

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Are there some way to add a cooments in my report when I ask for a parameters, before user execute it?

I'm ready adding a comment in a SQL Server Reporting Services, security option, and the user can read it when they pass the mouse on the option. But in this way I thinking that I will lost this in the next deploy, that is true?

Answer (score 3):

The comments added to reports won't be lost when you deploy the report again over this: When deploying reports from BIDS, some information is kept on the server. It's not a "Delete" then "load." The information kept is the security settings, the comments, some parameter information, such as default parameters and subscriptions.

Other than these comments stored in SSRS, there is not a way to add comments to the report before the display of the parameters. If you really need to do something like this, then you should build an interface to gather the parameters yourself and then display or redirect to the reports.